# Creating a link from node ID in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am checking out Drupal 8 and try to generate a link based on the node ID of an article. 
In Drupal 7 it is something like:

```
$options = array('absolute' => TRUE);
$nid = 1; // Node ID
$url = url('node/' . $nid, $options);
```

This results into an absolute link with the correct url-alias.

So the url()-function seems to be deprecated; what is the Drupal-8 way?
Looks like a really basic function for me but I could not find any useful references.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to use the [`\Drupal\Core\Url`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/class/Url/8) class, specifically its [`fromRoute`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromRoute/8) static method. Drupal 8 uses routes which have name different from their actual URL path. In your case, the route to use is the canonical route for a node entity: `entity.node.canonical`. `\Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute()` will not return a string, but an object. To get the URL as a string, you need to call its [`toString()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AtoString/8) method.

```
$options = ['absolute' => TRUE];
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 1], $options);
$url = $url->toString();
```

The static method is not easily testable, `$url->toString()` require an initialized container. Your can replace the static method with a call to [`UrlGeneratorInterface::generateFromRoute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21UrlGeneratorInterface.php/function/UrlGeneratorInterface%3A%3AgenerateFromRoute/8.2.x) on the [`url_generator`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/url_generator/8.1.x) service.

```
$options = ['absolute' => TRUE];
$url = $this->url_generator->generateFromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 1], $options);
$url = $url->toString();
```

Unfortunately, this method is marked as `@internal` so you are not supposed to use it in user code (ie. outside Drupal core).

Comment: this did it for me. thanks for the snippet! if an alias is defined i get the alias, if not I get the link with .../node/id.

Comment: Could you explain how to use it ? Where did I change / add code ? 
In theme > preprocess ? Url.php or the Core ?
It is difficult to find global answer when we start Drupal..

Comment: @PaulLeclerc You should never change something in the core just as a general note. You can use the code examples above wherever you need it. It works in every file where you can use php. We obviously can not answer this for you because we do not know what you want to do.

Answer (score 8):

Create absolute URL:

```
$options = ['absolute' => TRUE];
$url_object = Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid], $options);
// will output http://example.com/path-to-my-node
```

Create absolute link object:

```
$options = ['absolute' => TRUE, 'attributes' => ['class' => 'this-class']];
$node_title = Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create('<span>' . $node_title . '</span>');
$link_object = Drupal\Core\Link::createFromRoute($node_title, 'entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $nid], $options);
// will output <a href="http://example.com/path-to-my-node" class="this-class"><span>My Node's Title</span></a>
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you have fully loaded node object you can simply call `$node->toUrl()` to get required URL. By default it returns canonical URL for a node (*node/NID*) but it is possible to build other URLs listed in Node entity definition (see *Drupal\node\Entity\Node.php)*.
Same is true for other entity types.

```
$options = ['absolute' => TRUE];
$view_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('View'), $node->toUrl('canonical', $options));
$edit_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Edit'), $node->toUrl('edit-form', $options));
$delete_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Delete'), $node->toUrl('delete-form', $options));
```

Answer (score 2):

hehe, this is the shit in terms of getting URL from field (Twig version of getting that URL)

If you want the URL (and title) that is in a field you have to get to object of class:
**Drupal\Core\Url**

If you got the node by **drupal_entity** (Twig Tweaks) then you have: (I'll use "tab" as that node) **tab['#node'].field_link**

This gives you by using:

**tab['#node'].field_link.uri -> the URI** (URI is not URL)

**tab['#node'].field_link.title -> the title**

but, that's not the end.

it's better to acess **Drupal\link\Plugin\Field\FieldType\LinkItem** by:

**tab['#node'].field_link.get(0)**

**tab['#node'].field_link[0]**

(both do the same)

then you can access what's most interesting:

**tab['#node'].field_tab_link[0].getUrl()** a **Drupal\Core\Url** object.

You can access this object also by using this line below, from within that's node template file: **content.field_link[0]['#url']**  (this is also Drupal\Core\Url object)

That object has methods:

- **isExternal()**  -> is link to outside (ie. http://cnn.com)
- **isRouted()**     -> is link to inside of your site
- **getRouteName()**  -> name of the route
- **getRouteParameters()** -> which gives you an array of values, here(we get ID of that node) you would have ['node' => ID]

You should use it like that:

```
{% set tabURL = tab['#node'].field_link[0].getUrl() %}

{% if tabURL.isExternal() %}
    {% set link_path = tab['#node'].field_tab_link.uri %}

{% elseif tabURL.isRouted() %}
    {% set link_path = path(tabURL.getRouteName(), tabURL.getRouteParameters()) %} {# /node/12 #}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer for node edit link.

```
$nodeInfo = $entity->get('nid')->getValue();
$nodeId = $nodeInfo[0]['value'];
$options = ['absolute' => TRUE];
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form', ['node' => $nodeId], $options);
$url = $url->toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

I find it easier to work with the $node object.  Then let my IDE show me all the available methods of the object.  So the simplest is

```php
$link = $node->toLink();
```

This gets you a link to the full-page node, with the node title as the link text.

If you want to change the title/route, you could do something like

```php
$link = $node->toLink('Edit this node', 'edit-form');
```

Answer (score 2):

Full absolute path with correct language prefix:

```
$url_options = [
  'absolute' => TRUE,
  'language' => \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage(),
];
$Path = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 81], $url_options)->toString();
// prints https://example.com/fr/mon-page
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm ready to be downvoted here.  Apologize, I haven't completely accept this yet.

In  Drupal 7 took (only) 28 chars I can still remember and type  well.

```
l($node->title, $node->nid);
```

I guess something like this may improve the life quality of a D8 coder.

```
      function d8l ($text, $nid, $some_options)  {
         $options = [
           'query' => ['foo' => 'bar'],
           'fragment' => 'anchor-div',
           'attributes' => ['class' => ['my-class'], 'rel' =>'nofollow'],
         ];
         $link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t($text), 
         Url::fromUri('internal:/node/' . $nid, $options))->toString();
         return $link;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers here and lot of useful info. For edit links, if you have the node, I was able to do like this       `$options = [ 'absolute' => TRUE, 'language' => \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage(), ];`

and `editurl = $edit_node->toUrl('edit-form', $options)->toString();`

more info in `drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityInterface.php`